# How to hide specific odoo server action from action drop down for some records conditionally?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Here is my code.
I want to hide this action for some records conditionally?
I found some tutorials about ir.action.server but did not find the way to hide an action.

```
    <record id="ar_change_state_bulk_assign_id" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="name">Assign AR Number</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_olims_analysis_request"/>
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="code">self.bulk_change_states_pre("to_be_sampled",cr, uid, context.get('active_ids'), context=context)</field>
        <field name="sequence" eval="5"/>
    </record>
   <record id="ar_id_of_the_action_value_assing_ar" model="ir.values">
        <field name="name">Assign AR Number</field>
        <field name="action_id" ref="ar_change_state_bulk_assign_id"/>
        <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.server,'+str(ref('ar_change_state_bulk_assign_id'))"/>
        <field name="key">action</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_olims_analysis_request"/>
        <field name="model">olims.analysis_request</field>
        <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
    </record>
```

Comment: You cannot do that!! what you asking is not right what if you select multiple records so odoo will not know if he should show the action or not.

Comment: As @Cherif said, it's not possible to dynamically hide the Action. However, you can do validation within your action method to ensure it runs correctly and/or skips records that shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: Yes. Its not possible. Because context and domain do not work on actions. It is not possible (: