# How to hide custom Action from More Dropdown depending on an attribute?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-view

I have added some custom options to the Actions Dropdown using:

```xml
<act_window id="launch_session_wizard_xyz"
            name="Stornieren"
            src_model="x_dummy.dummy"
            view_type="form"
            res_model="x_dummy.storno_wizard"
            view_mode="form"
            target="new"
            key2="client_action_multi" />
```

How can we achieve that this Dropdown-action only is visible depending on an attribute?

For Buttons I can use the `attrs`. Attribute but I don`t know how this can be achieved with Action DropDown Elements

Comment: no ideas? any other workarounds for such solution?

Comment: It's not possible to dynamically hide the Action. However, you can do validation within your action method to ensure it runs correctly and/or skips records that shouldn't be allowed. Its not possible. Because context and domain do not work on actions. It is not possible. Answers taken from the duplicated question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850075/how-to-hide-specific-odoo-server-action-from-action-drop-down-for-some-records-c